# Update DropDownListFor data source from controller MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a DropDownListFor that takes data source from controller. Is there a way to update it since i'm adding new values that i want then to be displayed on the same page.

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, MyController.GetIds(Model.Id).Select(g => new SelectListItem { Text = g.Text, Value = g.Value }), @Resource.System_Choose, new
                   {
                       @class = "form-control selectpicker",
                       data_live_search = "true"
                   })
```

Controller:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetIds(int Id)
    {
        var retVal = new List<SelectListItem>();

        return retVal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your View deal with Model that has property of type `List<SelectListItem>()` and return this property ready to be binded and displayed in DropDown.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to achieve the goal,

1. Use only javascript to append the new value to select options. (If the new value doesn't send to backend)
2. Ajax and get the new list.

A sample for case 2, we can put the DropDownList to a partialview and use ajax to get the latest DropDownList in the partialview.

Controller :

```
public ActionResult QueryNewList()
{
    return PartialView("~/Views/Home/_urPartialView.cshtml", viewModel);
}
```

Html:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Js:

```
 $.ajax({
      dataType: "html",
      url: "QueryNewList",
      success: function (html) {
            $("#myDiv").html("");
            $("#myDiv").append(html);
       }
  })
```